# Transfer attribute from point to line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a point shapefile and a line shapefile like these:
[image: This is a minimal example]

Each point has a numerical attribute that I would like to transfer to the line (The lines represent directional data). I broke already the line at each point, but I don't know how to transfer the attribute from each point to the line. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial Join could work for this. [HERE](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) is the documentation.

However seeing how one point touches two line segments how are you deciding which point attributes will be joined? (two points will be touching the same line segments...)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, these lines represent directional data, which i have stored as an attribute in the lines as 1 and 2. So, let's say that the left one is from N to S, so it means that the first point you see will give the attribute to the 2nd line segment. I was thinking about defining this with an if statement. All I need to know is how to pass that attribute from the point to the line.

Comment: ah ok, I will update my answer then. Also how many point features are you working with?

Comment: and 'if' statement would work with the spatial join